# What is the correct way to indicate a NC (no connect) pin in Eagle CAD

Tags: eaglecad

I looked around for NC symbols etc. and off course, leaving pins hanging will throw errors when doing a design rules check. So what would be the best practice for indicating NC pins in Eagle CAD?

Comment: On [this old topic](http://www.eaglecentral.ca/forums/index.php/mv/msg/6824/23189/) is stated there is no NC symbol in Eagle. It might have changed, but if not: they say you can either make your own symbol or use a test point.

Comment: And also http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15943/what-does-the-x-mean-on-this-schematic/15944#15944

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I asked the same question of Cadsoft support only last week. I mentioned that I prefer to have a symbol on the schematic so that I know that I've properly reviewed that the pin in question can be left unconnected, the response I received was:

> We don't have an equivalent 'X' symbol in EAGLE. You could create your
>   own no-DRC symbol without a footprint, if you define it as an external
>   device it won't raise an error for not having a footprint. So that's a
>   feasible solution.

After finding that I couldn't add a schematic symbol without a package their follow-up was:

> See the HELP pages for the ATTRIBUTE and PACKAGE. The key to defining
>   a device as an external device is to create an attribute called
>   *EXTERNAL* in the device. This will allow you to create a part that doesn't need a package. This is handled in the library.

Comment: Nice solution, I didn't think of that! Thanks PeterJ!

Comment: Trying to create the symbol, but Eagle CAD doesn't like this!!!

Comment: This is exactly what I do. It looks like a little gray 'x' and has no pins.

Comment: The correct name of the attribute is `_EXTERNAL_`.

Comment: Here is a post how to do this attribute stuff:
https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/eagle-forum/feature-request-allow-devices-without-footprint-in-schematics/td-p/6994004

Answer (score 9):

There is no need for a explicit not-connected symbol.  Don't connect anything to it, and nothing will be connected to it, and that will be obvious in the schematic.  There really is no need to do anything more.

No, the DRC (Design Rule Check) doesn't care at all whether pins are connected.  The ERC (Electrial Rules Check) only complains about floating input pins, but then again those should be connected to something.

Comment: There is no *need* for this, you're right. I prefer to show that someone has seen that the pin is not connected and that is how it is supposed to be rather than just have the pin hanging off in space. Chacun à son goût and all that. :-)

Answer (score 2):

NC symbol can be very useful when Net classes are used. It is way how to create net with different net class (e.g. clearance matrix) for not-connected pin. General NC pin has default net class.